# Python can't open .py scripts on my pc but it can run them in execfile

Tags: python

I've been trying to fix this for 3 hours no to no avail. I installed Python 2.7.4 from

http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.4/

(clicked on the Windows x86 MSI Installer, not sure if program database is needed? maybe that's the problem)

and the python.exe works fine, and when I make text files with notepad++ then save them as .py, and then when i go into python.exe

I type Python file.py and everytime no matter what I type (whether I have arguments or not) it comes up with the SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax

BUT if I run the file as execfile("file.py") it works. The only problem is, if I'm trying to run a script with arguments, execfile can't pass arguments.

So could somebody please help me fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to run your script form within `python.exe` but directly from your console as follows:

```
python.exe file.py arg1 arg2 [...]
```

If the file association for `.py` is set correctly, you can probably even just type

```
file.py arg1 arg2 [...]
```

Comment: Gives me the can't open file 'file.py' Errno 2 no such file or directory. Even though the .py fiel is in the same folder as the python.exe. Or does it now have to be in the same folder as the cmd.exe??

Comment: You have to be in the same directory as `file.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take it even further. Save this line in a .bat script called "python"

```
@C:\Python27\python.exe %*
```

And put that .bat file under C:\Windows\System32

This will make it so that you don't have to type "python.exe" at the command line every time you want to run a python script.

I like the method above better than messing with environment variables.